# How to set default value of Mat-Select when options are retrieved from API

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular6

I have the following `mat-select` control, whose options are loaded dynamically from the server on `ngOnInit`:

```
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <mat-select placeholder="Category" formControlName="patientCategory">
          <mat-option>--</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let category of patientCategories" [value]="category">
            {{category.name}} - {{category.description}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>

        <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['patientCategory'].hasError('required')">
          Please select a category
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

The control is part of the form group called `form`, which I am building with `this.formBuilder.group({})`. The control is inside a component with a function called `populateStep`.

```
populateStep(value: PatientStepModel) {
    // Set values of other controls..

    // Categories have been retrieved
    if (this.patientCategories.length > 0) {

      // Must set reference for MatSelect
      const toSelect = this.patientCategories.find(c => c.id == category.id);
      this.form.get('patientCategory').setValue(toSelect);

    } else {
      this.logger.trace('No categories exist, will set category at the end of HTTP call..');
      this.categoryToSelect = value.category;
    }
  }
```

As the above code shows, when an external component calls the `populateStep` function, the function checks to see if the categories have been loaded from the server. If the categories are there, I am able to set the value of the select.

However, if the categories are empty, i.e. the HTTP call is still in progress, I have to set the `categoryToSelect` variable and do the same selection inside of the `subscribe` callback.

```
  private loadPatientCategories(): void {

    this.operationCategoryService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        results => {
          this.patientCategories = results;

          if (this.categoryToSelect) {
            // Must set reference for MatSelect
            const toSelect = this.patientCategories.find(c => c.id == category.id);
            this.form.get('patientCategory').setValue(toSelect);
          }
        },
        error => {
          this.notificationService.openSnackBar('An error occurred');
        }
      );
  }
```

I am not happy with this solution as it requires me to do the same thing in multiple places, is there a better solution? Perhaps set timeout before setting the category? Although I can't be sure how long the HTTP call will take..

Comment: please add you'r code into [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: @Esen are you subscribing to an observable value.. if yes have you tried just using the subscribe() or you definitely need to call your populateStep() method ?

Comment: populateStep() is called by a parent component. I am subscribing to the category http call as shown in the code. I tried setting the value of the mat-select in the subscribe but sometimes the populateStep() is called after retrieving the categories from the server. To handle both cases, I added the if in the populateStep().